# File Explorer won't display PowerShell Modules directory otherwise visible in $env:psmodulepath

Tags: powershell, powershell-module, microsoft-file-explorer

I'm in the process of learning how to create powershell modules through this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKstEJKdc4o&t=3661s - the video itself is not important.

I learned from learn.microsoft.com that powershell will have the following module directories by default:

$PSHome\Modules (%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules)

$Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules (%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules)

$Env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules (%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules)

however there is no C:\users\john\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules folder visible in File Explorer, while it's clearly visible in $env:psmodulepath when I run this from PowerShell. I'm able to navigate all the way to C:\Users\john\Documents\WindowsPowerShell but **there is no Modules directory**. I did enable hidden folders display and did also check Documents folders for OneDrive, Public, Administrator users. This is not a work/school computer, this is my own PC.

Can someone please help me understand why this Modules folder is visible in $env:psmodulepath but not in File Explorer?

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a location exists in `$env:psmodulepath`, doesn't mean it actually has to exists in the file system.

You can add any random location to `$env:psmodulepath` without it actually existing. PowerShell will just skip any locations that don't exist.

With a fresh Windows account, there isn't even a `WindowsPowerShell` directory under `$env:userprofile\documents`, to use a user profile or modules you have to create those directories.

It is fairly easy for a user to create a new directory, but a little bit more tricky to add a new entry to `$env:psmodulepath`. I guess that is why they already put it in there, even though it may never be used.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful. I did suspect something like that. Thanks for your response.